# collaborative drawing/ live drawing

Tags: javascript

I wasn't sure where in the world I could post this one... So I have an idea for making a little drawing toy, but I am not sure on how I would implement this (on a data structure level)...

I am wanting to perhaps have a 1920 x 1080 window where I can have a paint brush and draw lines (just like paint), but here is the kicker. I want be able to save this drawing real time. The idea is that I can open a web browser and watch myself draw from another window... essentially collaborative paint.

Has this been done and are there any projects anyone can point me to as to how I could get started developing this?

There was a similar post to this, but it was three years old and I would like some recent input.

The biggest question is particularly the best data structure I could use to store this in a database for real time editing (or if that is even a good solution)

thanks!! :)

Comment: Have you looked at [WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)?

Comment: I've done a project like this. It was 2 years ago and just an alpha version. But I think it's still a good way to do it. I used nodejs and websocket. You can find the project here: https://github.com/Clemzd/collaborativeCanvas

Comment: I've develop something like this and the solution was websocket.

Comment: Awesome! this will really help me getting started!

Answer (score 5):

This would be relatively straight forward to do.

From a web based aspect...

You could use something like an HTML5 Canvas.

Then you can use JavaScript and do something like this:

```
document.onmousemove = function(event){
xcoor = event.pageX;
ycoor = event.pageY;
}
```

to capture mouse movements whenever you move the mouse.

You can also use the code to put a circle or square (square in this case but you can use a circle easily) as follows:

```
document.onmousemove = function(event){
xcoor = event.pageX;
ycoor = event.pageY;
mapcan.fillStyle = "#000000";
mapcan.fillRect(-1*(11617845.3461), -1*(8093417.14653), 10, 10);
}
```

Now you can use PHP or some other language to insert the cordinates into a database.

Trying to do live editing with multiple users is complicated at best. I would suggest sticking with a live view instead.

While this is resource intensive it will work.

Hope this helps if you dicide to build it!

Comment: I like this! Whats so interesting about it is because, I am wanting to be able to do it from IOS, that is why the database. Basically, What I want is to be able to have a clear image back ground so I can play around drawing mustaches anything and everything that is on the screen. I already have my clear applications on my computer, but the whole idea is that I can sit there on my iphone and draw stuff on my computer screen.

Comment: Hmmmm... Have you looked into collaborative drawing programs online, a quick Google search should present a few?

Comment: This is one that I saw a big ago that I kind of liked. https://github.com/byrichardpowell/draw   My only concern is developing it purely in web then not being able to interface it with an ios app

Comment: I don't think that you should try to do this as an app as well. You will need to adjust the code I gave you to work on mobile but trying to get an app to work with a web program is going to be a pain in the butt.. also would that app "Draw with friends" or whatever it is called suit your needs? I'm not sure what features that app offers.

Comment: What I am really wanting to do is essentially have a slate on my ios device that I can draw on, and it will come up on a web browser. (because I am doing another project with clear windows which will alow me to place video or images behind it) to simply draw over

Comment: Hmm.. With all do respect, with the amount of work that is involved why not get a "Wacom" drawing tablet? Then you can use paint or some other drawing program in combination with it... the drawing tablets are even wireless if you pay enough.